# Location of "Usage History" in Google App Engine new Console

Tags: google-app-engine

I am unable to see where the former Usage History option is now located into the new Admnin Console Interface for Google App Engine. In the previous one was located at the left side navigation bar.

It was a very useful view of your daily application resource consumption moreover the aggregate monthly view.

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking for is located under

`Your Project -> Compute -> App Engine -> Quota Details`

If you want to know your quotas of certain Google APIs, it is located in

`Your Project -> APIs -> Enabled APIs (tab)`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think they added it (yet ?) in the new console, or I never found it...

You can access it via the old admin console anyway: https://appengine.google.com/billing/history?&app_id=s~YOUR_APP_ID